# Nginx configuration with Laravel API + vuejs

Tags: laravel, nginx, vue.js

I have the application with frontend on vuejs which works through the laravel api on backend. And I use Laravel Passport for authorization.
When I start the application through the integrated laravel web server (artisan serve) on localhost:8000 it works good without any errors.
But when I moved it to my local web server I got some problems.

When I try to do the post request

```
axios.post('http://project.local/oauth/token', data)
```

I get the http error **405 (Method Not Allowed)**.
I excluded all routes from CSRF-token, added CORS headers and anyway it doesnt work. As I said on localhost:8000 it works well.

I didn't find any information about this problem and couldn't do it by myself. Does anyone know anything about it? Thanks in advance.

My nginx config

```
    server {
    listen  80;

    root /home/me/project/frontend/dist;
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name project.local;

    access_log off;
    error_log /home/me/project/backend/error.log notice;

    location / {
    index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }

    location /api/v1 {
         root /home/me/project/backend/public;
         rewrite ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /oauth/token {
        root /home/me/project/backend/public;
        rewrite ^/oauth/token/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

            set $newurl $request_uri;
            if ($newurl ~ ^/api/v1(.*)$) {
                set $newurl $1;
                root /home/me/project/backend/public;
            }

            if ($newurl ~ ^/oauth/token(.*)$) {
                set $newurl $1;
                root /home/me/project/backend/public;
            }

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $newurl;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: @samayo It's not the point. I just changed names for stackoverflow and did the syntax mistake

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a **cache**! I just solved this problem and it turned out to be a cache **cloudflare**

cached all files as index.html